# Value at Risk forecast generator

Tags: python, performance, beginner

I am developing a code to compute Value at Risk (VaR) using various models (see below). Currently, I am looking to implement a rolling window approach over a dataset spanning 4,000 days, with each window covering 500 days. My goal is to generate 3500 VaR forecasts using different VaR models within this rolling window framework.

However, I've noticed that the calculations for a single day across all models currently take approximately one second. This means that the rolling window computation is quite time-consuming. I'm seeking guidance on how to optimize the code for better performance.

Since I'm relatively new to Python, any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also, any other hint or tip on the code would be good! I have copied the relevant parts of the code below.

Time results with this code (one iteration over all models for one forecast day, potentially over 5,000 iterations needed for anaylsis):

```
The function 'variance_covariance' took 0.0014 seconds to complete.
The function 'historic' took 0.0016 seconds to complete.
The function 'ewma' took 0.0581 seconds to complete.
The function 'monte_carlo_normal' took 0.0161 seconds to complete.
The function 'evt_monte_carlo_gumbel' took 0.0521 seconds to complete.
The function 'garch_normal' took 0.0349 seconds to complete.
The function 'garch_t' took 0.0548 seconds to complete.
All functions took 0 minutes and 0.2216 seconds to complete.
```

````py
# Standard library imports
import functools
import math
import time
import warnings

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Related third-party imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import yfinance as yf
from arch import arch_model
from IPython.display import HTML, display
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import exponweib, gumbel_r, kurtosis, norm, shapiro, skew, t
from tqdm import tqdm

# Suppress warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


# Define a list of ticker symbols
ticker_list = ["^GSPC", "^N225", "GC=F", "000001.SS", "VBMFX", "^IXIC", "VWO"]

# Define corresponding names for the assets
name_list = [
    "S&P 500 Index",
    "Nikkei 225 Index",
    "Gold",
    "Shanghai Composite Index",
    "Vanguard Bond Index Fund",
    "Nasdaq Index",
    "Vanguard FTSE EM Index ETF",
]

# Define portfolio weights (you can choose either equal weights or custom weights)
weights = np.full(
    shape=len(ticker_list), fill_value=1 / len(ticker_list)
)  # Equally weighted portfolio

# Define the start and end dates for historical data
start_date = "2001-01-01"
end_date = "2021-12-31"


def get_stock_prices(ticker_list, name_list, start, end):
    """
    Retrieves the adjusted closing prices for a list of assets from Yahoo Finance.

    Parameters:
    - ticker_list (list): List of asset codes from Yahoo Finance.
    - name_list (list): List of corresponding asset names.
    - start (str): Start date for data retrieval (YYYY-MM-DD).
    - end (str): End date for data retrieval (YYYY-MM-DD).

    Returns:
    - portfolio_prices (DataFrame): DataFrame containing adjusted close prices of the assets.
    """
    stock_prices = pd.DataFrame()

    for ticker, name in zip(ticker_list, name_list):
        stock_price = yf.download(ticker, start=start, end=end)
        stock_price.rename(columns={"Adj Close": name}, inplace=True)
        if stock_prices.empty:
            stock_prices = stock_price[name].to_frame()
        else:
            stock_prices = stock_prices.merge(
                stock_price[name], right_index=True, left_index=True
            )

    return stock_prices


# Execution
stock_prices = get_stock_prices(ticker_list, name_list, start_date, end_date)

if stock_prices is not None:
    # Calculate log-returns
    daily_return = np.log(stock_prices / stock_prices.shift(1)).dropna()

    # Display prices and returns
    print("\nAdjusted Closing Prices:")
    display(stock_prices)
    print("\nLog-Returns:")
    display(daily_return)
else:
    print("No data available.")


# Covariance matrix
cov_matrix = daily_return.cov()

# Correlation matrix
corr_matrix = daily_return.corr()

print("\nCovariance Matrix:")
display(cov_matrix)

print("\nCorrelation Matrix:")
display(corr_matrix)


# Check Returns and Weights array lengths
if daily_return.shape[1] != len(weights):
    raise ValueError(
        "The number of columns in 'daily_return' does not match the length of 'weights'."
    )
else:
    print("The number of columns in 'daily_return' does match the length of 'weights'.")

# Print other information (optional)
# print(daily_return.shape, len(weights))
# print(daily_return.columns)


# Time Tracker per VaR Model
# Boolean flag to control timing decorator
enable_timing = False  # Set to True to enable timing, False to disable


# Timing decorator with condition
def timing_decorator(func):
    """Measure execution time of each function."""

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if enable_timing:  # Check if timing should be enabled
            start_time = time.time()  # Record the start time before function execution
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)  # Execute the function
        if enable_timing:  # Check if timing should be enabled
            end_time = time.time()  # Record the end time after function execution
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time  # Calculate calculation time
            print(
                f"The function {func.__name__!r} took {elapsed_time:.4f} seconds to complete."
            )
        return result

    return wrapper


class ValueAtRisk:
    """
    A class to calculate various Value at Risk (VaR) methods.
    """

    # Constants
    AMOUNT = 100  # 100 for percentage VaR/ES values or invesmtent amount for absolut VaR/ES values
    CONFIDENCE_LEVELS = {
        "95%": 0.05,
        "99%": 0.01,
    }  # Dictionary of confidence levels and their corresponding significance levels
    SIMULATIONS = 100000  # Number of Monte Carlo simulations
    CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_95 = CONFIDENCE_LEVELS[
        "95%"
    ]  # Significance level for 95% confidence
    CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_99 = CONFIDENCE_LEVELS[
        "99%"
    ]  # Significance level for 99% confidence

    def __init__(self, daily_return, weights):
        """
        Initialize the class with daily returns and portfolio weights.

        Args:
            daily_return (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame of daily returns.
            weights (list): List of portfolio weights.
        """
        self.daily_return = daily_return
        self.weights = weights
        self.cov_matrix = (
            daily_return.cov()
        )  # Compute the covariance matrix of daily returns

    def calculate_portfolio_metrics(self):
        """
        Calculate common portfolio metrics.

        Returns:
            tuple: Portfolio mean, standard deviation, and portfolio returns.
        """
        daily_mean = np.average(self.daily_return, axis=1, weights=self.weights)
        port_mean = daily_mean.mean()  # Calculate portfolio mean return
        port_stdev = np.sqrt(
            np.dot(self.weights.T, np.dot(self.cov_matrix, self.weights))
        )  # Calculate portfolio standard deviation
        portfolio_returns = np.average(
            self.daily_return, axis=1, weights=self.weights
        )  # Calculate portfolio returns

        return port_mean, port_stdev, portfolio_returns

    def calculate_var_es(self, confidence_level, portfolio_returns):
        """
        Calculate VaR and ES for a given confidence level.

        Args:
            confidence_level (str): Confidence level, e.g., "95%" or "99%".
            portfolio_returns (np.array): Portfolio returns.

        Returns:
            tuple: VaR and ES values.
        """
        var_percentile = np.percentile(
            portfolio_returns, self.CONFIDENCE_LEVELS[confidence_level] * 100
        )  # Calculate VaR at the specified confidence level
        es = np.mean(
            portfolio_returns[portfolio_returns <= var_percentile]
        )  # Calculate ES

        return var_percentile, es

    def compute_var_es(self, port_mean, port_stdev, portfolio_returns):
        """
        Compute VaR and ES values given portfolio statistics.

        Args:
            port_mean (float): Portfolio mean return.
            port_stdev (float): Portfolio standard deviation.
            portfolio_returns (np.array): Portfolio returns.

        Returns:
            tuple: VaR and ES values.
        """
        z_scores = norm.ppf([self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_95, self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_99])

        var_values = port_mean + z_scores * port_stdev  # Compute VaR values

        es_95 = np.mean(
            portfolio_returns[portfolio_returns <= var_values[0]]
        )  # Compute ES at 95% confidence
        es_99 = np.mean(
            portfolio_returns[portfolio_returns <= var_values[1]]
        )  # Compute ES at 99% confidence

        return var_values, (es_95, es_99)

    def compute_portfolio_returns(self):
        """
        Compute portfolio returns.

        Returns:
            np.array: Portfolio returns.
        """
        return np.average(self.daily_return, axis=1, weights=self.weights)

    # ------------------- Variance-Covariance VaR -------------------
    def variance_covariance(self):
        """
        Compute Parametric VaR using the variance-covariance method.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR and ES values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Calculate portfolio mean return, standard deviation, and portfolio returns
        port_mean, port_stdev, portfolio_returns = self.calculate_portfolio_metrics()

        # Compute VaR and ES for different confidence levels
        var_values, es_values = self.compute_var_es(
            port_mean, port_stdev, portfolio_returns
        )

        # Organize results into a dictionary for VaR and ES and return as a DataFrame
        var_dict = {}
        for confidence_level, var_value in zip(
            self.CONFIDENCE_LEVELS.keys(), var_values
        ):
            var_dict[f"VaR({confidence_level})"] = var_value
            es_95, es_99 = es_values
            var_dict[f"ES({confidence_level})"] = {
                "95%": es_95,
                "99%": es_99,
            }[confidence_level]

        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

    # ------------------- Historical Simulation VaR -------------------
    def historic(self):
        """
        Compute Historical VaR.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR and ES values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Compute portfolio returns using historical data
        portfolio_returns = self.compute_portfolio_returns()

        # Initialize a dictionary to store VaR and ES values
        var_dict = {}

        # Calculate VaR and ES for each confidence level
        for confidence_level in self.CONFIDENCE_LEVELS.keys():
            var_percentile, es = self.calculate_var_es(
                confidence_level, portfolio_returns
            )
            var_dict[f"VaR({confidence_level})"] = var_percentile
            var_dict[f"ES({confidence_level})"] = es

        # Return the results as a DataFrame
        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

    # ------------------- EMWA VaR -------------------
    @timing_decorator
    def ewma(self, lambda_factor=0.94):
        """
        Compute VaR using the Exponentially Weighted Moving Average (EWMA) method.

        Args:
            lambda_factor (float): Smoothing parameter for EWMA.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR and ES values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Convert daily returns to numpy array
        daily_returns = self.daily_return.values

        # Calculate squared returns
        returns_squared = daily_returns**2

        # Initialize an EWMA covariance matrix
        ewma_cov_matrix = self.daily_return.cov().values

        # Update the covariance matrix iteratively
        for t in range(1, len(self.daily_return)):
            returns_vector = daily_returns[t]
            returns_squared_vector = returns_squared[t]

            # Update the EWMA covariance matrix
            ewma_cov_matrix = (
                lambda_factor * ewma_cov_matrix
                + (1 - lambda_factor) * np.outer(returns_vector, returns_vector)
                + (1 - lambda_factor) * ewma_cov_matrix * returns_squared_vector
            )

        # Calculate portfolio mean return, standard deviation, and portfolio returns
        port_mean, port_stdev, portfolio_returns = self.calculate_portfolio_metrics()

        # Compute VaR and ES for different confidence levels
        var_values, es_values = self.compute_var_es(
            port_mean, port_stdev, portfolio_returns
        )

        # Organize results into a dictionary for VaR and ES and return as a DataFrame
        var_dict = {}
        for confidence_level, var_value in zip(
            self.CONFIDENCE_LEVELS.keys(), var_values
        ):
            var_dict[f"VaR({confidence_level})"] = var_value
            es_95, es_99 = es_values
            var_dict[f"ES({confidence_level})"] = {
                "95%": es_95,
                "99%": es_99,
            }[confidence_level]

        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

        # ------------------- Monte Carlo VaR Normal -------------------

    @timing_decorator
    def monte_carlo_normal(self):
        """
        Compute Monte Carlo VaR considering the correlation between assets.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR and ES values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Calculate mean returns and covariance matrix for assets
        asset_mean_returns = self.daily_return.mean()
        cov_matrix = self.daily_return.cov()

        # Simulate returns using a multivariate normal distribution
        simulated_returns = np.random.multivariate_normal(
            asset_mean_returns, cov_matrix, self.SIMULATIONS
        )

        # Calculate portfolio P&L by dot product of simulated returns and weights
        portfolio_pnl = np.dot(simulated_returns, self.weights)

        # Calculate VaR percentiles and Expected Shortfall (ES)
        var_percentiles = np.percentile(
            portfolio_pnl,
            [self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_95 * 100, self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_99 * 100],
        )
        es_95 = np.mean(portfolio_pnl[portfolio_pnl <= var_percentiles[0]])
        es_99 = np.mean(portfolio_pnl[portfolio_pnl <= var_percentiles[1]])

        # Organize results into a dictionary for VaR and ES and return as a DataFrame
        var_dict = {
            "VaR(95%)": var_percentiles[0],
            "VaR(99%)": var_percentiles[1],
            "ES(95%)": es_95,
            "ES(99%)": es_99,
        }

        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

    # ------------------- Monte Carlo Extreme Value Gumbel -------------------
    @timing_decorator
    def evt_monte_carlo_gumbel(self):
        """
        Compute Extreme Value Theory Monte Carlo VaR using the Gumbel distribution.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Calculate mean returns and covariance matrix for assets
        asset_mean_returns = self.daily_return.mean()
        cov_matrix = self.daily_return.cov()

        # Simulate returns using a multivariate normal distribution
        simulated_returns = np.random.multivariate_normal(
            asset_mean_returns, cov_matrix, self.SIMULATIONS
        )

        # Calculate portfolio P&L by dot product of simulated returns and weights
        portfolio_pnl = np.dot(simulated_returns, self.weights)

        # Select top 10% block maxima for Gumbel distribution fit
        block_maxima = -np.sort(-portfolio_pnl)[: int(0.1 * self.SIMULATIONS)]

        # Fit a Gumbel distribution to block maxima
        loc, scale = gumbel_r.fit(block_maxima)

        # Generate Gumbel losses
        gumbel_losses = -np.random.gumbel(loc, scale, self.SIMULATIONS)

        # Calculate VaR percentiles
        var_percentiles = np.percentile(
            gumbel_losses,
            [self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_95 * 100, self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_99 * 100],
        )

        # Calculate Expected Shortfall (ES)
        es_95 = np.mean(gumbel_losses[gumbel_losses <= var_percentiles[0]])
        es_99 = np.mean(gumbel_losses[gumbel_losses <= var_percentiles[1]])

        # Organize results into a dictionary for VaR and ES and return as a DataFrame
        var_dict = {
            "VaR(95%)": var_percentiles[0],
            "VaR(99%)": var_percentiles[1],
            "ES(95%)": es_95,
            "ES(99%)": es_99,
        }

        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

    # ------------------- GARCH VaR Normal -------------------
    @timing_decorator
    def garch_normal(self):
        """
        Compute GARCH VaR using a normal distribution and calculate ES empirically.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR and ES values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Compute the weighted average return of the portfolio
        weighted_avg = pd.DataFrame()
        weighted_avg["weighted_avg"] = (
            np.average(self.daily_return, axis=1, weights=self.weights) * 100
        )

        # Fit a GARCH model with a normal distribution
        am = arch_model(
            weighted_avg["weighted_avg"], vol="Garch", p=1, o=0, q=1, dist="normal"
        )
        res = am.fit(disp="off")
        forecasts = res.forecast()
        cond_mean = forecasts.mean.iloc[-1].values
        cond_var = forecasts.variance.iloc[-1].values

        # Calculate z-scores for the specified confidence levels
        z_scores = norm.ppf([self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_95, self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_99])

        # Calculate Value at Risk (VaR)
        value_at_risk = cond_mean + np.sqrt(cond_var) * z_scores
        var_95, var_99 = value_at_risk

        # Calculate Expected Shortfall (ES)
        es_95 = np.mean(
            weighted_avg[weighted_avg["weighted_avg"] <= var_95]["weighted_avg"]
        )
        es_99 = np.mean(
            weighted_avg[weighted_avg["weighted_avg"] <= var_99]["weighted_avg"]
        )

        # Organize results into a dictionary for VaR and ES and return as a DataFrame
        var_dict = {
            "VaR(95%)": var_95 / 100,
            "VaR(99%)": var_99 / 100,
            "ES(95%)": es_95 / 100,
            "ES(99%)": es_99 / 100,
        }

        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

    # ------------------- GARCH VaR Skewed-t -------------------
    @timing_decorator
    def garch_t(self):
        """
        Compute GARCH VaR using a skewed-t distribution.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR and ES values.
        """
        # Determine the calculation date as the maximum date in daily returns plus one day
        date = self.daily_return.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

        # Compute the weighted average return of the portfolio
        weighted_avg = pd.DataFrame()
        weighted_avg["weighted_avg"] = (
            np.average(self.daily_return, axis=1, weights=self.weights) * 100
        )

        # Fit a GARCH model with a skewed-t distribution
        am = arch_model(
            weighted_avg["weighted_avg"], vol="Garch", p=1, o=0, q=1, dist="skewt"
        )
        res = am.fit(disp="off")
        forecasts = res.forecast()
        cond_mean = forecasts.mean.iloc[-1].values
        cond_var = forecasts.variance.iloc[-1].values

        # Calculate quantiles for the specified confidence levels
        q = am.distribution.ppf(
            [self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_95, self.CONFIDENCE_LEVEL_99],
            res.params[-2:],
        )

        # Calculate Value at Risk (VaR)
        value_at_risk = cond_mean + np.sqrt(cond_var) * q
        var_95, var_99 = value_at_risk

        # Calculate Expected Shortfall (ES)
        es_95 = np.mean(
            weighted_avg[weighted_avg["weighted_avg"] <= var_95]["weighted_avg"]
        )
        es_99 = np.mean(
            weighted_avg[weighted_avg["weighted_avg"] <= var_99]["weighted_avg"]
        )

        # Organize results into a dictionary for VaR and ES and return as a DataFrame
        var_dict = {
            "VaR(95%)": var_95 / 100,
            "VaR(99%)": var_99 / 100,
            "ES(95%)": es_95 / 100,
            "ES(99%)": es_99 / 100,
        }

        return pd.DataFrame(var_dict, index=[date])

    # ------------------- Summary -------------------
    def VaR_summary(self):
        """
        Generate a summary of all VaR calculations.

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: DataFrame with VaR summary scaled by the specified amount.
        """
        # List of VaR calculation methods
        methods = [
            "Parametric",
            "Historical Simulation",
            "EWMA",
            "Monte Carlo (Normal)",
            "EVT Monte Carlo (Gumbel)",
            "GARCH (Normal)",
            "GARCH (Skewed-t)",
        ]

        # Calculate VaR and ES for each method and store in a list
        calculations = [
            self.variance_covariance(),
            self.historic(),
            self.ewma(),
            self.monte_carlo_normal(),
            self.evt_monte_carlo_gumbel(),
            self.garch_normal(),
            self.garch_t(),
        ]

        # Create a dictionary mapping method names to their corresponding VaR and ES calculations
        results = dict(zip(methods, calculations))

        # Concatenate the results into a summary DataFrame
        summary = pd.concat(results, axis=0)

        # Scale the results by the specified amount (100 for percentage VaR/ES or investment amount for absolute VaR/ES)
        summary *= self.AMOUNT

        return summary


# Record the start time
start_time = time.time()

# Execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create an instance of the ValueAtRisk class with daily returns and weights
    VaR = ValueAtRisk(daily_return, weights)

# Calculate the VaR summary using the VaR_summary method
summary_df = VaR.VaR_summary()

# Calculate total execution time
end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time
minutes, seconds = divmod(total_time, 60)

# Print out the total execution time
print(
    f"All functions took {int(minutes)} minutes and {seconds:.4f} seconds to complete."
)

# Print the results
print("\nValue at Risk and Expected Shortfall one-day ahead Forecast (in %):")
display(summary_df)

# Define the rolling window length as a constant
ROLLING_WINDOW_LENGTH = 503

# Record the start time
start_time = time.time()

# Initialize an empty DataFrame to store results
results_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Calculate the total number of iterations
total_iterations = len(daily_return) - ROLLING_WINDOW_LENGTH + 1

# Define a custom bar format
custom_bar_format = (
    "{desc}: {percentage:3.0f}%|\x1b[32m█{bar}\x1b[0m| Iteration {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} "
    "[Elapsed Time: {elapsed}, Remaining Time: {remaining}, Rate: {rate_fmt}]"
)

# Initialize dictionaries to store the calculation times for each method
calculation_times = {
    "variance_covariance": 0,
    "historic": 0,
    "ewma": 0,
    "monte_carlo_normal": 0,
    "evt_monte_carlo_gumbel": 0,
    "garch_normal": 0,
    "garch_t": 0,
}

# Initialize the tqdm progress bar
with tqdm(
    total=total_iterations,
    desc="Rolling Window",
    unit="iteration",
    bar_format=custom_bar_format,
    ascii=False,
) as pbar:
    start_time = time.time()  # Record the start time

    # Loop through the data using the rolling window
    for end in range(ROLLING_WINDOW_LENGTH, len(daily_return) + 1):
        # Slice the data for the rolling window
        window_data = daily_return.iloc[end - ROLLING_WINDOW_LENGTH : end]

        # Calculate VaR for the current window using the methods in the ValueAtRisk class
        VaR = ValueAtRisk(window_data, weights)

        # Calculate and display the execution time for individual methods
        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.variance_covariance()
        calculation_times["variance_covariance"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.historic()
        calculation_times["historic"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.ewma()
        calculation_times["ewma"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.monte_carlo_normal()
        calculation_times["monte_carlo_normal"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.evt_monte_carlo_gumbel()
        calculation_times["evt_monte_carlo_gumbel"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.garch_normal()
        calculation_times["garch_normal"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        start_method_time = time.time()
        VaR.garch_t()
        calculation_times["garch_t"] += time.time() - start_method_time

        current_summary = VaR.VaR_summary()

        # Append the results to the results_df
        results_df = pd.concat([results_df, current_summary])

        # Update the tqdm progress bar
        pbar.update(1)

        # Calculate elapsed time
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

        # Calculate estimated remaining time
        remaining_iterations = total_iterations - pbar.n
        estimated_remaining_time = (elapsed_time / pbar.n) * remaining_iterations

        # Update the progress bar with remaining and elapsed time
        pbar.set_postfix(
            Elapsed=f"{elapsed_time:.0f}s", Remaining=f"{estimated_remaining_time:.0f}s"
        )

# Calculate the total execution time for all iterations
total_execution_time = time.time() - start_time

# Display the total calculation times for each method
print("\nTotal Calculation Times per Method:")
for method, time_elapsed in calculation_times.items():
    print(f"{method}: {time_elapsed:.2f} seconds")

# Display the results DataFrame
print("\nRolling Window Value at Risk and Expected Shortfall Forecasts (in %):")
display(results_df)

# Print the total execution time
minutes = int(total_execution_time // 60)
seconds = int(total_execution_time % 60)
print(
    f"\nTotal execution time for all iterations: {minutes} minutes and {seconds} seconds"
)
```
````

Comment: Greetings! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/287718/revisions#rev-body-329d701d-80eb-4552-89a2-59c1a2c594dc) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: There's some review context missing. Tell us about `daily_return`, please. Also, show us some example timing runs for N ticker symbols, so we can reproduce that "one second" figure and maybe improve it.

Comment: Hi, thanks @J_H! 
The return dataframe  `daily_returns`, consists currently of seven portfolio assets with 3,735 daily returns. (Data retrieved from Yahoo).
I figured out that the VaR EMWA model was a bottleneck, and I was able to bring calculation time over all models down to ~0.3 ms per rolling day by vecorization . I changed the code in my post above to reflect this latest change.  I also copied the results of the time tracker. 
As I will run large datasets courious to see if the code can be optimized further. Also any other feedback on the code is much appreciated.

Comment: @Oscar, very good. The fatal-error roadblock I continue to hit, even with your recent edits, is in evt_monte_carlo's call to gumbel_r.fit(), which complains "TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method". I had tried to fake up a dataframe with: daily_return = pd.DataFrame( np.zeros((NUM_PERIODS, len(ticker_list))), columns=ticker_list, index=pd.date_range(start="2019-10-01", periods=NUM_PERIODS, freq="Q"), ) . Apparently I need to produce the dataframe in some different way, such as with fewer zeros. The OP code offers me no guidance :-(

Comment: @J_H, many thanks! I have updated above the code to include my daily_returns dataframe as well as some other changes to the code I did in the meantime. I hope this facilitates some deeper analysis. Many thanks in advance for your help!